# Integrated SQL-Server in NodeJS Application

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, npm

is it possible to integrate a sql-server (don't really care what sql-server(mssql,mysql, mongodb, oracledb)) into a nodejs application?

so when i start the nodejs app it starts the integrated sql server which i then can use.

something like this(pseudocode):

```js
const sqlServer = require('embedded-sql-server');
var sqlserverInstance = sqlServer('rootUser', 'rootPassword'); // startup with root username+password
sqlserverInstance.setup({
dataStore: './sql-storage/', /* where to store files */
encoding: 'utf8mb4'}); // setup default tables
sqlserverInstance.start();

sqlserverInstance.database['AccountsAndUsers'].query('SELECT * FROM userAccounts', (result, err) => {});
```

does something like this exist? or would this even be a good idea to think about or just garbage?

( got the idea from Microsoft Azure *MySQL in App* )

Comment: not fully sure of what you ask, but sql server is the sql db version of microsoft, and yes you can use it in Nodejs app and they have they own package check here https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHussien this is a sql client. I want the server integrated in my node.js app

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHussien i mentioned that i don't really care what sql-server(mssql,mysql, mongodb, oracledb)

Comment: yeah I got what you mean now, I have no idea if there is something like this exist, but I believe it will not be a good approach if it is, as if something happened to your backend server that is integrated with the db and the system crashed, the db will be crashed also and there will be no access to the db.

Comment: although it is possible to implement something like this from scratch using file system by saving the data into json files or txt, but you will have to maintain the storage and the read/write to these files, and also the creation

Comment: i thought about development such system by myself but idk if this is worth it. thanks for the help. maybe i'll develop this at some time...

Comment: Just an idea... Have you tried messing with SQLite? Since SQLite doesn't need a server, you could make your Node.js server *the* SQL server.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes thats one great idea. i didn't even think about sqlite. i'm currently working on a little tool class for sqlite with nodejs/expressjs. i'm gonna post it as answer to this thread and close it afterwards